# Why can't I find the UEFI Firmware setting on my Lenovo?

Tags: windows-10, uefi

Please explain me. I can't find UEFI Firmware setting on my lenovo laptop (windows 10).I will tell from start to end.At first, my laptop has windows 7.And then I installed Ubuntu 16.04(No dual bot).Then I deleted Ubuntu system & installed windows 10.And then I installed remix os (dual bot).Then I remove Remix Os from dual bot.Now I want to install back Ubuntu (dual bot or using Virtual box).It is not easy.I can't find UEFI Firmware setting or Boot menu.

[image]

It show that  BIOS mode is legacy. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The legacy mode has obviously been enabled within UEFI to support the legacy boot of operating systems that do not support UEFI. Your Windows installation obviously is NOT an UEFI installation, but rather a legacy installation itself.

You can enable the UEFI-boot in the "boot" or "startup" settings most of the times within BIOS/UEFI (in my case it is under startup). Change the Boot Mode from Legacy to UEFI. Then you can enable Secure Boot (normally a different point in menu tree) too (which you should if you only run Windows 8/10). You then have to reinstall your whole OS - boot from an UEFI disk/usb/pxe etc.

An UEFI-Installation of an operating system is required to directly get to the UEFI-Settings from the OS and have the full integration features between the UEFI and the OS.

If you really want to have a dual-boot environment you can either stay with BIOS and use the ubuntu installer to make it dualboot or go with UEFI dualboot - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook for instructions to achieve that.

Comment: _"If you really want to have a dual-boot environment, it will probably be very hard to get it working with UEFI."_ - citation needed. I'm dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu, both in UEFI mode, with CSM off. No issues whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks @gronostaj - you are correct, I edited my above comment and added a link to achieve dualboot with UEFI for Windows and Ubuntu